# Forward raw mail from s3 to SES via lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

My current setup:

1. SES Inbound rule that stores email to s3 bucket and sends message to SNS topic
2. Lambda function that listens to messages on topic

Lambda code:

```js
import { s3 } from "./libs/s3Client.mjs";
import { GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

import { ses } from "./libs/sesClient.mjs";
import { SendRawEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
 
const getObject = (Bucket, Key) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({Bucket, Key})
        
        try {
            
            const response = await s3.send(getObjectCommand)
            
            return await resolve(response.Body.transformToString());
        } catch(err) {
            return reject(err)
        }
    })
}

export const handler = async(event) => {
    var msgInfo = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message)
    console.log(msgInfo)
    
    let action = msgInfo.receipt.action
    
    let rawMail = await getObject(action.bucketName, action.objectKey)
    
    rawMail = rawMail.replace(/From: .*/, 'From: ' + '<some other email>')
    
    const sendRawEmailCommand = new SendRawEmailCommand({
        RawMessage: { Data: rawMail },
        Destinations: ['some-other-destination']
    })
    
    let response = await ses.send(sendRawEmailCommand)
    console.log(response)
    
    
};
```

But after executing, I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
```

I have tried converting the raw mail to an array, which removes the error but just sends the raw mail as plain text.

Comment: Where is `.transformToString` from? Try `.toString()` instead meanwhile...

Answer (score 4):

The "Data" object needs to be a buffer in v3 of the SDK:

```
const sendRawEmailCommand = new SendRawEmailCommand({
    RawMessage: { Data: Buffer.from(rawMail) },
    Destinations: ['some-other-destination']
})
```

You'll also likely need to modify the headers so the Email is being sent from a verified Email address/domain.

Comment: Only answer that worked for me on the internet